# How do i populate a list with a group of data members

Tags: c#

I would like to seek some knowledge in creating a list of two sets of data member from two different classes, one parent, one inherited.

To put this into context i'm trying to populate a list with a pre-set of information. My first question is **"what is the best approach to do this?** I would like to create a list that contains information about the "enemy". So for example the "name", "description" and "abilities" are data members of the ENEMY class, and the "hp", "mana" and "ap" data members are inherited from the parent class "PERSON". i need to overwrite the original values set in the parent class and apply these along with the three data members into a list so that i can call upon a specific index and retrieve the data members i need based on the index of that enemy. I was told by a friend the only way to make this list was at run time by creating an array for each data member and looping through to input say 10 names, 10 hp's, and then looping through all these to apply them into the relevant index in the list? is this true?  My question is **"how do i populate a list with a number of data members to apply 6 separate pieces of information into one index of a list"?** my code is linked below to try and help.

```
 public string Name;
    public string description;
    public string abilities;
    PERSON P2 = new PERSON();

  public void populateList()
    {

        ENEMY [] name = new ENEMY[10];


            name[0] = "goblin";
            name[1] = "orc";
            name[2] = "Troll";
            name[3] = "hydra";
            name[4] = "dragon";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) /

                Enemies.Add(name[i]);

            }

    }
```

Data members from parent class PERSON

```
 public int hp;
    public int mana;
    public int ap;

    public PERSON()
    {
        hp = 100;
        mana = 100;
        ap = 100;
    }
```

An example of what i'm after is something like this:

Enemies = new List();

""inside the list is as follows""

<0> Goblin, A foul Creature, Claw, 100 (hp), 50 (mana), 50 (ap).
<1> Orc, A tall horrible creature, Cleave, 500 (hp), 50 (mana), 50(ap)
etc etc

each element in the list has all the data members and that way if i call:

Enemies.name etc i cant quite fully remember how to call a certain index in a list

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: I've edited the question a little to include some form of example if that helps

Comment: BTW @user3366235 if you use the "@" symbol and my name I'll get notified that you posted a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a list of enemies from your code.  I'm assuming you have a class called `Enemy`.  The way I would do this is like this:

```
List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();
Enemies.Add(new Enemy() { name = "Goblin", hp = 50, mana = 50, description = "A foul Creature" });
Enemies.Add(new Enemy() { name = "Orc", hp = 500, mana = 50, description = "A tall horrible creature" });
```

Then you could access these like any other list.  If I've misunderstood, leave a comment.